# How to do Tally-like operation on list based on elements' total in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

For example, I have a list like:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {6}, {4, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 2, 3, 2}, {9}, {7}, {2, 5}}
```

And I want to get a tallied list based on the total of the lists' elements.

In this case, I want the output to be:

```
{{6, {{1, 2, 3}, {6}}, {7, {{2, 5}, {1, 6}, {7}}}, {9, {{4, 5}, {2, 2, 3, 2}, {9}}}}}
```

How to do this conveniently in Mathematica?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not really a `Tally`-like operation, since it stores all instances. It is more of a `Gather`-like operation.

Comment: I see. thank you Simon, as always!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my attempt - a little simpler than Yoda's

```
lst = {{1, 2, 3}, {6}, {4, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 2, 3, 2}, {9}, {7}, {2, 5}};

{Total@First@#, #} & /@ GatherBy[lst, Total]
```

If you don't want repeated elements, then you could use

```
{Total@First@#, Union[#]} & /@ GatherBy[lst, Total]
```

Or if you really wanted a tally-like operation

```
{Total@First@#, Tally[#]} & /@ GatherBy[lst, Total]
```

Comment: Deleting mine. Your solution is far simpler than what I had (and it didn't have the right format either) :)

Answer (score 4):

While I would probably do this just as @Simon did, let us not forget that `Reap` and `Sow` can be used as well:

```
Reap[Sow[#, Total[#]] & /@ lst, _, List][[2]]
```

where `lst` is the original list. This will be somewhat less efficient than the `GatherBy`- based code, but also pretty fast. One can speed up the above code about 1.5 times by rewriting it as

```
Reap[Sow @@@ Transpose[{lst, Total[lst, {2}]}], _, List][[2]]
```

in which case it becomes about 1.5 times slower than the code based on `GatherBy`. Note that the speed difference between the two methods is not very dramatic here, because the list is ragged and therefore not packed, and `GatherBy` does not have here the speed advantage it normally enjoys for packed arrays.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I keep forgetting about the `Tr` - my bad :). Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Don't overlook `Tr`.  This is shorter *and* faster:

```
{Tr@#, {##}} & @@@ GatherBy[lst, Tr]
```

Comment: I measure it as 2.095 times faster and 79.487% shorter! +1